# Selected Items in MVC select list are null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following model -

```
public class RoleModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<UserModel> SelectedUsers { get; set; }

    public RoleModel()
    {

    }
}
```

The users IEnumerable is a list of users who are currently assigned to the selected role. When the View loads, this is populated correctly.

When I press Save in the view, the SelectedUsers IEnumerable and the Users IEnumerable is null, meaning I cannot unassign all users and reassign the selected users to the role.

Any ideas why the IEnumerables are null when pressing Save?

[image: Screenshot showing null IEnumerables]

**View**

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedUsers, new SelectList(Model.Users, "Id", "SurnameFirstName"))
```

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        RoleModel role = _roleService.GetById(id);

        if (role == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(role);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(RoleModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _roleService.ReassignRights(model);
            _roleService.ReassignUsers(model);
            _roleService.Update(model);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**Reassign Users method in RoleService.cs**

```
public void ReassignUsers(RoleModel role)
    {
        var roleDal = _roleRepository.FindById(role.Id);

        //_roleRepository.ClearUsersForRole(role.Id);

        foreach (var user in role.SelectedUsers)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the type of `UserModel` into type of of UserModel's PK. If `UserModel::Id` is `int` then change the `SelectedUsers` as below.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<int> SelectedUsers { get; set; }
```

While the `Users` property will still be null because there is no input that is related to `Users`, it's just being used to render the html options in the `ListBoxFor`. You need to set the value again when it's submitted.

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jOwlMn)